# Surface Fitting for a pair of coupled differential equations

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I a pair of coupled differential equations which solve for two variables, fe and fi. I have from a separate source, two surface plots - or quantities R_data and S_data, which I plot against fe and fi (from data).

In the differential equation for fe, there is a quantity R and in the differential equation for fi, there is a quantity S. I would like to fit the surfaces for the quantities R and S (vs. fe and fi from the differential equation) to the surfaces that I already have (R_data and S_data).

I have tried to use fminsearch for the same. However, fminsearch minimizes the error only for one surface/curve, and I have two surfaces to fit from the same set of differential equations. How would I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

fminsearch will minimize whatever function you feed into it.  You could write your own function which returns the sum of the error from the two surfaces (or some other combination of the errors), then fminsearch will attempt to minimize this combination of errors.

Comment: I have currently done that, the sum of the two errors of the two surfaces. However, that doesn't seem right to me - that would not individually fit the two surfaces, am I not right?